# Came across a Redux function that takes a dispatch as a param before dispatching action, unclear how it works

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm working on a new codebase and came across a Redux function that looks like this:

```
const googleLogin = authData => dispatch => dispatch(socialLogin('google-oauth2', authData));
```

I was trying to figure out exactly how it works as I've never seen anything like this.

I'm not looking for the result of the function so much as an explanation of the function itself.

I understand taking a param called `authData` but what's throwing me off is the `dispatch` param before the actual dispatch action takes place.

Any insight is hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a typical Redux "thunk action creator":

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#action-creators

Thunks are a technique for writing Redux logic that needs to use `dispatch` and `getState` ahead of time, without knowing what Redux store instance you'll be working with.